# Count element selected in nested json

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I have to count length of a jsonArray but i'm able to do it. This is the example from start:

https://jsfiddle.net/vuqcopm7/13/

Summary, if you click over an item of the list, for example "asd1" it will create an input text for each time you click that item or the others. What i need is count how many times that item is clicked, or better, how many input that item creates. Is it possible? For example instead:

```
asd1 (numberForEachItemSelected)
```

if i create 2 input, because i tap over it 2 times, it will be:

```
asd1 (2)
```

everything in angularjs

Comment: I'm aware this may be a hack more-so than a elegant solution, but is something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/aq4v8x21/ what you're after?

Comment: What is the use case? Can you push the input objects into child array of the item you click on? Then use length

Comment: @KreepN i can't modify the json :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vuqcopm7/35/)

I changed the push pushItems function to increment a 'clicks' key I added to 'attributes', then I bound that to the view:

```
$scope.pushItems = function pushItems(attribute, items) {
            items.clicks++
            //do stuff..
}
```

If you can't modify your model to add the 'clicks' key server side, adding this if statement will either add to the clicks key, or set it if it doesn't exist:

```
$scope.pushItems = function pushItems(attribute, items) {
        if (items.clicks) {
            items.clicks++
        } else {
            items.clicks = 1
        }
        // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Well, your solution works well but the json you modified adding the "click" it arrives from server and i can't change it. Have you got another way?

Comment: What do you mean you can't change it?  Do you need to store the number of clicks or no?

Comment: You added: "clicks": 0 in the json right? I can't change the json manually. It comes from the server and i can't change it. I need to do what you have done! Shows the count for each item.. but without change the json. Is it possible?

Comment: ok see if that works.  Even if you can't modify the model server-side, you can just add the key to the model client-side and use it to store the clicks value..

Comment: And you need to modify your question to be a little bit more clear.  I understood what you were asking, but apparently most people do not, andI can see how it is a little bit confusing.  Don't depend on the fiddle to show what your problem is.  Explain it fully in the OP, documented with code.

Comment: Yes, it works.. now i'm going to modify the question! Thank you. Only one more problem. When i remove an item it removes all items.

Comment: yep...I noticed.
You'll need to have the remove button track by index and remove that particular index you are clicking on...It will be slightly more involved than that, but that's basically what needs to happen.

Comment: Yes it's exactly what i need to do but i can't do it..i already use indexOf but seems not working

Comment: Of course if you can help me i will be glad